# Understanding the plm package - Why aren't my standard errors correct?

Tags: r, regression, panel-data

For fun, I tried to replicate the results of [Petersen (2009)](http://rpproxy.iii.com:9797/MuseSessionID=248c435aa056d82d70d390e949c628fb/MuseHost=rfs.oxfordjournals.org/MusePath/content/22/1/435.abstract) who deals with the correct estimation of standard errors in finance panel data sets.

In a nutshell, he estimates the following standard regression for a panel data set:

$$
Y_{it} = X_{it} \beta + \epsilon_{it}
$$

where $\epsilon_{it} = \gamma_i + \eta_{it}$ and $x_{it} = \mu_{i} + \nu_{it}$. Hence, both the residual and the independent variable have a firm-specific component. Petersen goes on to show that this results in biased standard errors when applying the standard OLS. For example, he shows in table 1 of his paper that if both the residual volatility and the variable volatility are driven by 50% by a firm-specific component, the true standard errors are nearly twice as large as the ones given by OLS.

He shows that in a MCS and I reproduced those results in R, as you can see from the code below. Naturally, I asked myself how I would compute the correct standard errors in R and the package of choice seemed to be `plm`. However, I just don't get the correct results out of it and I don't know what I miss.

Here is my code:

```
library(plm)
runMCS <- function(runs, nrN, nrT, fracFirmX, fracFirmEps, sd_X, sd_eps, beta) {

  betas    <- numeric(runs)
  se_betas <- numeric(runs)
  panel_betas    <- numeric(runs)
  se_panel_betas <- numeric(runs)

  for (i in 1:runs) {

    #Model epsilon, X, and Y
    eps <- rep(rnorm(nrN, 
                     mean=0, 
                     sd = sd_eps * sqrt(fracFirmEps)), 
               each=nrT) + 
                 rnorm(nrN * nrT, mean=0, sd = sd_eps * sqrt(1-fracFirmEps))
    X   <- rep(rnorm(nrN, 
                     mean=0, 
                     sd = sd_X   * sqrt(fracFirmX)),   
               each=nrT) + 
                 rnorm(nrN * nrT, mean=0, sd = sd_X   * sqrt(1-fracFirmX))
    Y   <- beta * X + eps

    #Compute regression (OLS)
    reg <- summary(lm(Y ~ X))

    #Save results
    betas[i]    <- reg$coef[2, 1]
    se_betas[i] <- reg$coef[2, 2]

    #Try plm
    df <- data.frame(Firm = rep(1:nrN, each=nrT),
                     Time = rep(1:nrT, times=nrN),
                     Y = Y,
                     X = X)
    preg <- summary(plm(Y ~ X, data=df, index=c("Firm", "Time"), effect="individual", model="within")) #within is fixed effects
    panel_betas[i]    <- preg$coef[1, 1]
    se_panel_betas[i] <- preg$coef[1, 2]
  }

  return(c(avg_beta = mean(betas), 
           true_se = sd(betas), 
           avg_se = mean(se_betas), 
           avg_clustered = mean(panel_betas),
           se_clustered = mean(se_panel_betas)))

}
MCS_50_50 <- runMCS(50, 500, 10, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 2, 1)
MCS_50_50
     avg_beta       true_se        avg_se avg_clustered  se_clustered 
   1.00503955    0.06020203    0.02825567    1.00433092    0.02985546
```

Note that I only run the simulation 50 times here because the plm function slows it down considerably. So basically, it makes virtually no difference if I call `lm` or `plm`. I'm pretty confident that I set the `index` and `model` option correct after reading the vignette of the package. However, I must miss something here! Interestingly, the package also has the `fixef` function and if I call that on one run, I get something like  this:

```
summary(fixef(plm(Y ~ X, data=df, index=c("Firm", "Time"), effect="individual", model="within")))
1      13.60377     0.44112    30.8391 < 2.2e-16 ***
2    -830.74707     0.44136 -1882.2236 < 2.2e-16 ***
3    -326.96042     0.44137  -740.7840 < 2.2e-16 ***
4     169.16463     0.44246   382.3287 < 2.2e-16 ***
...
```

I'm not quite sure how to interpret those results, but here, I get considerably larger standard errors for each firm separately. If I would average those, I would end up with something above 0.44 which is considerably closer to the true standard errors, but still not right.

So, again a very long question from me, sorry for that ;-) Note that I did check answers before and I found this interesting [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10017/standard-error-clustering-in-r-either-manually-or-in-plm). The white paper that is referred to in the answer is interestingly the same person that implemented the solution on Petersen's [webpage](http://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/petersen/htm/papers/se/se_programming.htm). So I'm pretty sure that I could get the correct standard errors by implementing Mahmood Arai's solution. But I'm looking for an already implemented and therefore safe option and I just wonder why that plm function does not work.

Comment: The manual states "If the argument vcov was specified, the standard errors (stored as attribute "se" in the return value) are the respective robust standard errors". I don't see that you used the ``vcov`` argument above: user11562's shows you one way to use the ``vcov`` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it just

```
coeftest(xxx, vcov=function(x) vcovHC(x, cluster=c("group","time")))
```

where `xxx` is the outcome of the `plm()` function?

Comment: Sorry for the late delay; anyways, your approach doesn't really change my standard errors and your proposed solution is going again in the direction of the link I provided above.  That is, computing the standard errors yourself. I am just wondering why plm is not doing that automatically?